# Prevent radio buttons from losing checked state when updating name attribute via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a collection of HTML elements that is structured and hierarchical. When an element is added or removed, I update its sibling elements so that the correct sequence order is reflected in the element attributes. Part of this operation involves updating name attributes on radio buttons.

Due to radio buttons being grouped by name, changing the names results in the "checked" state of the radio button being lost.

For an example of the problem I am encountering, check out http://jsfiddle.net/UNQjU/12/ - check a radio button and then execute the code and you will see that state is lost. I am looking for a workaround that will allow me to maintain the checked state of each radio button while I manipulate the name attribute.

Comment: It looks like it might be an artifact of jsFiddle.  Have you tried this code outside of it??

Comment: What do you mean check a radio button and then execute the code? When you click run on jsFiddle it completely reloads the bottom right iframe. As soon as the code is run your jQuery is executed.

Comment: Woops... you ate correct. I will update the jsfiddle when I can to execute on a button click. I am experiencing this problem outside of jsfiddle as well.

Comment: Apparently there is something else in my code that is causing my problem. I've updated the jsFiddle and it appears that changing the name attribute has no effect on the checked state, but when I remove the line in my actual code that alters the name, my problem goes away. When I get to the bottom of it I'll update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine in the JS Fiddle example you have. If you change the HTML to:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" checked="checked"> Option 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1"> Option 2 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1"> Option 3 <br/>
```

Then 'Run' the fiddle, the checkbox name gets changed and the checkbox remains checked.

Don't forget about labels

```
<label for="group1_a">
    <input type="radio" id="group1_a" name="group1" checked="checked">
    Option 1</label><br/>
<label for="group1_b">
    <input type="radio" id="group1_b" name="group1">
    Option 2</label><br/>
<label for="group1_c">
    <input type="radio" id="group1_c" name="group1">
    Option 3</label><br/>
```